# How much XP can a Bottle of Enchanting give?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I used a bottle of enchanting that I bough from a villager, and just ONE single orb popped out. Worst trade deal ever. The trade was 10 emeralds.

Was that a glitch?

Answer (score 4):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bottle_o%27_Enchanting):

> A bottle o' enchanting can be thrown by pressing use. On impact it will drop experience orbs worth 3–11 experience points.

If you are curious about how many points it takes to level up, each level you increase requires even more points to advance to the next level.  [Here is a table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Leveling_up) on the wiki.  Unfortunately, 3-11 points is not very much.

Comment: Also note that a single orb may have multiple experience in it.